# Creating Extended Python Type Object within Embedded Interpreter C/C++

Tags: python, c++, embedding, extending

I'm trying to define a new python type object using the documentation found here https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes.html. At the moment I am just following the basics section defining a new type with the same names as used in the documentation. I am then embedding the python interpreter within a simple application by calling `PyImport_AppendInittab("noddy", &PyInit_noddy);` followed by `Py_Initialize();` and then I am running a simple python script using `PyRun_SimpleString(script);` where "script" is actually the following

```py
import noddy
mytest = noddy.Noddy()
```

which is within the documentation as an example of creating an object of the new extended type. The problem I am having is that this produces an error

```
TypeError: cannot create 'noddy.Noddy' instances
```

What am I doing wrong here? I appreciate I have not provided any source code but I have simply copied the example from the documentation. I understand what each part is doing but I cannot find a problem. The module called noddy is created, the Noddy object is added so why can I not create a `noddy.Noddy()` object as stated in the documentation?

Comment: I am having the same issue not even embedding or anything.

Comment: In my case, I had not realized I needed to tweak include/pyconfig.h .
(Using MinGW-w64 together with Python 3.4-amd64 from python.org).
I used a version that MSYS managed to generate with ./configure